# <form> disabled my javascript code

Tags: javascript, forms

I create a small program for developing my own feelings, but there is a problem. Everything is ok until the `<form>` tag is used, JavaScript stops working completely.

```js
var tytul = document.getElementById("k-title");
var opis = document.getElementById("k-description");
var popup = document.getElementById("info_box");
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
var podsumowanie = document.getElementById("summary");

$("#add").on("click", function() {
  var id = $(".wiersz").length;
  $('#tabela').append('<tr class="wiersz"><td class="komorka-lewa"> <input id="cecha_' + id + '" type="text" placeholder="Cecha produktu"> </td><td class="komorka-prawa"><input id="cecha-opis_' + id + '" type="text" placeholder="Opis cechy produktu"></td></tr>');
  document.getElementById("default-table").style = "display: none";
});

$("#add_photo").on("click", function() {
  var sciezka = prompt("Podaj link do zdjęcia");
  var opis = prompt("Podaj opis zdjęcia dla wyszukiwarek");
  $("#gallery").append('<div class="photo-container"><button class="del">Usuń zdjęcie</button><img src="' + sciezka + '" class="photo" alt="' + opis + '"/></div>');

  if ($(".photo").length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("default-gallery").style = "display: none";
  }
  $(".del").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
    document.getElementById("default-gallery").style = "display: block";
  });
});

$("#gen").on("click", function() {

  if (opis.value.length < 1 || tytul.value.length < 1) {
    popup.style = "display: block";
    overlay.style = "display: block";
    document.getElementById("infobox-content").innerHTML = "Uzupełnij wszystkie potrzebne dane, zanim wygenerujesz kartę produktu.";
  } else {
    popup.style = "display: block";
    overlay.style = "display: block";
    document.getElementById("infobox-content").innerHTML = "Karta została wygenerowana, plik z kodem znajduje się w katalogu generate.";
    podsumowanie.innerHTML = "Tytuł: " + tytul.value + "<br>" + "Opis produktu: " + opis.value + "<br>" + "Cecha produktu: " + cecha + "<br>" + "Opis cechy produktu: " + cechaopis;
  }
});

$("#close").on("click", function() {
  popup.style = "display: none";
  overlay.style = "display: none";
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.wiersz {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
}

#tabela {}

.komorka-lewa {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-align: right;
  border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.komorka-prawa {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

#tabela {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  width: 100%;
}

.cecha,
.cecha-opis {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: 0;
}

#gen {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#add,
#gen,
#add_photo {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#add:hover,
#gen:hover,
#add_photo:hover {
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

#container {
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

#info_box {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 500px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#info_box p:first-child {
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#info_box,
#overlay {
  display: none;
}

#info_box>p span {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}

.photo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.photo:first-child {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.photo:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#default-gallery {
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  padding: 5px;
}

.photo-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.photo-container:first-child {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.photo-container:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.del {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 25px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.del:hover {
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info_box">
  <p>Informacja <span id="close" style="float: right;">x</span></p>

  <p id="infobox-content"></p>
</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>

<div id="container">

  <form method="post" action="">

    <div style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
      <input type="text" value="" id="k-title" placeholder="Tytuł karty" style="display: block; width: 100%; font-size: 30px; border: 0; background: 0; margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">
      <input type="text" value="" id="k-description" placeholder="Krótki opis" style="display: block; width: 100%; border: 0; background: 0; text-align: justify; padding: 10px;">
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px;">Specyfikacja techniczna</div>

    <table id="tabela" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px">
      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" id="default-table">Brak dodanej specyfikacji</td>
          <tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <button style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;" id="add">Dodaj wiersz</button>

    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #eee; font-weight: 200; line-height: 0.92em; padding: 23px 0; font-size: 30px;">Galeria zdjęć</div>
    <div id="default-gallery">Brak dodanych zdjęć</div>

    <div id="gallery">
    </div>

    <button style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;" id="add_photo">Dodaj zdjęcia</button>

    <input id="gen" type="submit" value="Generuj kartę" />
</div>

</form>

<div id="summary">
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rLmh3n8/)

Comment: put your jsfiddle code in question.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work, what is the expected result, what is the error?

Comment: Please add your code, what errors do you see in the console? Which tag is being used. Please clearly detail your problem, what code there is and what steps you have taken so far to debug your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4rLmh3n8/ look at this

Comment: After adding the <form> tag, they stop adding images and doing it as normal

Comment: I don't know exactly what to expect, so it's pretty hard to help you with that. Javascript is working here. The only thing that I've found is a </div> closing before the </form>.

Comment: @sc4rface a jsfiddle is a nice addition to the question, but you **must** always include a minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem directly within your question and not as external link. An external site might be temporary down, not reachable from certain region, or going down forever.

Comment: As I say - javascript stops working when there is <form> in the code, more precisely - clicking on the "add row" or "add photos" button does nothing, I'll add that after removing the <form> tag, all JS code works. As if something blocked him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that inside the form, the first button is considered to be the submit button if no buttons have their type defined.

It's always best to explicitly specify the button type.

So instead of

```
<button ...></button
```

use

```
<button type="button" ...></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change this part of button element code

```
<button style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;" id="add">Dodaj wiersz</button>
```

to:-

```
<button style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;" id="add" type="button">Dodaj wiersz</button>
```

type attribute button is required if we are using javascript on button or else it acting by default as a submit button in form tag

Comment: Seriously? Was it so easy? Thank you very much, problem solved :D